# Drawing circle the manual way in java returning strange result

Tags: java, trigonometry

I am trying to draw a circle with its origin in the middle of the screen:

```
width = canvas.getWidth();
height = canvas.getHeight();

BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
if(bufferStrategy == null){//If bufferStrategy is not initialized yet
    canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
    bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
}
Graphics graphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();

public int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

int radius = height / 6;
for(int theta = 0; theta < 360; theta++){
    double rads = Math.toRadians(theta);

    double x = (width / 2) + (Math.cos(rads) * radius);
    double y = (height / 2) + (Math.sin(rads) * radius);
    pixels[(int)(x + y * width)] = 0xFFFF00FF;
}

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);

graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
```

But I am getting a weird result:

[image: Result]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, **complete**, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? For example, where did you get the `graphics` instance?

Comment: @ToddSewell Done!

Comment: Does the image look correct if you save the `BufferedImage` to a file? (try [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) if you don't know how)

Comment: @ToddSewell No, the same output is given, so therefore the problem lays in the circle drawing algorithm!

Comment: Could you try using the [`BufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,%20int,%20int)) method? Your curent approach feels a little strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast your x and y values to ints before doing the math to figure out which of the pixels to change the color of.

```
int x = (int) ((width / 2) + (Math.cos(rads) * radius));
int y = (int) ((height / 2) + (Math.sin(rads) * radius));
pixels[(x + y * width)] = 0xFFFF00FF;
```

Doing it inline resulted in some rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the math for indexing into `pixels` array.  The formula of `x + y * width` is expecting discrete values for `x` and `y`.  However as it stands `y * width` is calculated as a double value, leading to the pixels being partially offset from the left side of the image even when `x=0`.

You need to make sure `x` and `y` are normalized into `int` values before they are used in the formula for indexing into `pixels`:

```
pixels[(int)x + (int)y * width] = 0xFFFF00FF;
```

This gives the expected result.